# Tcl object method called as variable

Tags: tcl

How can one execute an object method as a variable?

```
oo::class create handlerTest {
    method onEvent {} {
        puts "onEvent method"
    }
}

set testObj [handlerTest new]
#set wrapper {$testObj onEvent}
#set wrapper {$testObj::my onEvent}
#set wrapper [namespace code {$testObj onEvent}]
#set wrapper "eval testObj onEvent
#set wrapper {[eval testObj onEvent]}
$wrapper
```

All of the above attempts appear to execute `$wrapper` as a single command, not a command with args.

As I am using an external library that calls the defined wrapper, I can't change how the wrapper is called (i.e. `{*}$wrapper`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible... but slow and a bit tricky!

Comment: Did I miss something here? If the wrapper is invoked with the expansion operation in front, doesn't `set wrapper [list $testObj onEvent]` work?

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
proc theWrapper {} [
    upvar 1 testObj testObj
    tailcall $testObj onEvent
}
set wrapper theWrapper
$wrapper
```

Comment: Better yet, use `tailcall $testObj onEvent` so the helper procedure cuts itself out of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to rewrite the command name itself is via an unknown handler (defaults to being called `unknown` in the global namespace; you probably want to use that default). Some care needs to be taken when doing this, as the default handler does things that some code needs to have present; a bit of shuffling around with `rename` should do the trick.

```
# only want special treatment for some commands
set autoexpanded [list $testObj]

# save for later
rename unknown _original_unknown

proc unknown args {
    global autoexpanded
    # if we want to expand the first word...
    if {[catch {lindex $args 0 0} cmd] == 0 && $cmd in $autoexpanded} {
        # delegate to the expanded command (tailcall is perfect here)
        set args [lassign $args cmd]
        tailcall {*}$cmd {*}$args
    } else {
        # delegate to the original unknown
        tailcall _original_unknown {*}$args
    }
}
```

Be aware that this is not a fast dispatch mechanism. It is only used when the only other alternative is throwing an error because the command doesn't exist (also slow, but error paths are never optimal or heavily optimized).

Comment: You do not want to use a general expand-everything rule, not without some care to make sure that there is no infinite recursion possibility (listing the *existing* commands you want to do this for in the `autoexpanded` variable should be easy enough). You also want to avoid trickery if you can do things correctly without going this route.

Comment: Thanks, Donal. I'm assuming there's nothing we can put in the command string to "trick" the interpreter into doing the expansion?

Comment: There used to be such a hack (to support itcl if I remember right) but it got taken out because it was such an ugly weird hack. The answer above is much less horrible!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method that comes to mind, is to generate a name for an alias and put that in the variable:

```
set testObj [handlerTest new]
set wrapper [interp alias {} wrapper[incr wrapperid] {} $testObj onEvent]
$wrapper
```

=> onEvent method